# Как выровнять flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 196px;
  height: auto;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

form {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item h3 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.menu {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-us {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.footer {
  font-size: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>PayLab</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://paylab.tk/css/main.css">
  <style>
    img[alt="www.000webhost.com"] {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo col-xl-3">
        <a href="https://paylab.tk/"><img src="https://paylab.tk/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item col-xl-3 offset-sm-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item1.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/mts.php/">Мтс</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item2.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/megafon.php/">МегаФон</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item3.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/beline.php/">Билайн</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item4.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/rostelecom.php/">Ростелеком</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item5.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/motiv.php/">Мотив</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item6.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/yota.php/">Yota</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Убрать класс offset-sm-3 для первого блока или прописать margin-left: 0
что я и сделал в коде ниже

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.offset-sm-3 {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

img {
  width: 196px;
  height: auto;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

form {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item h3 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.menu {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-us {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.footer {
  font-size: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>PayLab</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://paylab.tk/css/main.css">
  <style>
    img[alt="www.000webhost.com"] {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo col-xl-3">
        <a href="https://paylab.tk/"><img src="https://paylab.tk/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item col-xl-3 offset-sm-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item1.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/mts.php/">Мтс</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item2.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/megafon.php/">МегаФон</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item3.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/beline.php/">Билайн</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item4.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/rostelecom.php/">Ростелеком</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item5.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/motiv.php/">Мотив</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-xl-3">
          <img src="https://paylab.tk/img/item6.png" alt="">
          <h3><a href="https://paylab.tk/yota.php/">Yota</a></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```